# Advanced search in Django

Tags: django, advanced-search

I am working on a social blogging site using Django and I need to create an advanced search bar with filters like location and authors. I do have a basic one working as of now. Can someone help me with the concept on how to add filters to it. couldn't find much related stuff with django. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to retrieve data from a database, using the Django ORM, you can use the `filter` method of the `Queryset` class.
That said, we can't help you more without a context, how you expect the filters to behave, the models behind the scene, or anything more than "how to conceive an advanced search in Django"...